# Loop video with hover ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to autoplay a video when rendered, but only once. On the hover effect, I would like it to play the video with a loop. I have tried to use event.target.play() on mouseOver but have had no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```js
<video 
  className="videos" 
  autoPlay={true} 
  onMouseOver={event => event.target.play()} 
  onMouseOut={event => event.target.pause()} 
  muted={true}
  src={prompt}>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onEnded event along with mouseover to loop it. Also using useRef makes it easy to set/play instead of passing event from all the callbacks. Check below code,

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import testVideo from "./testVideo.mp4";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);

  const loop = () => {
    ref.current.play();
  };

  const onEndedLoop = () => {
    if (focus) loop(); // when ended check if its focused then loop
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (focus) loop(); // when focused then loop
  }, [focus]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Loop video with hover ReactJS!</h2>
      <video
        id="video"
        ref={ref}
        style={{ width: "300px" }}
        autoPlay
        onMouseOver={() => setFocus(true)}
        onMouseOut={() => setFocus(false)}
        muted={true}
        src={testVideo}
        onEnded={onEndedLoop}
      ></video>
    </div>
  );
}
```

check working demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/loop-video-on-hover-qegu7

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked great. Now would you happen to have any advice on how to make this available for 5 videos on a single page? I tried to make some workarounds because of the useRef() only works for a single video. Would I just create these function multiple times? I am sure there is a much more efficient way. Thank you again :) greatly appreciated

Comment: You may want to ask this as new question since your original question is answered.

Comment: @IcarusBuckhold: for multiple video elements, you need separate refs to work with. so you can create refs array, and pass index to event handlers to make further changes. no need to create separate event handlers. I would appreciate if you mark above answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

@Madhuri has good answer (Which I upvoted).
However, if we add a function to pause loop when not focused, that will loop the video only when in focus and stop when not hovering over or not in focus.

```
const loop = () => {
    ref.current.play();
  };

  const pauseLoop = () => {
    ref.current.pause();
  };

  const onEndedLoop = () => {
    if (focus) loop(); // when ended check if its focused then loop
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (focus) loop(); // when focused then loop
    if (!focus) pauseLoop(); // when not focused then pause loop
  }, [focus]);
```

Comment: When adding the pauseLoop function in the useEffect, that loses the ability for autoplay to run on the first render of the page. Is there anyway to change this so that focus is not false or true. Making the focus true requires that I hover and move away from the video to force it to stop or else it keeps looping no matter if my mouse is hovering or not. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: Sure, if u set `const [focus, setFocus] = useState(true)`  When the page load, since focus is true, video will play. It will also play on hover over. However, once you hover away, the video will pause until you hover in again.